# Why I can't change my username in Terminal?

Tags: users, username

I started working recently with Ubuntu and changed my username. I changed the **"v" tiny** by **capital "V"**, but in Terminal remains the same.

Comment: What name you want to change? What you have done?

Comment: i changed my username

Comment: http://imgur.com/HRWemTk

Comment: I think he is doing a little confusion. I think he is confusing **username** with **account name**. Am I right, guys?

Comment: The 'User Accounts' GUI changes the [GECOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gecos_field) *full name* (equivalent to using the command-line `chfn` command). The `PS1` string uses the short-form username `\u`: AFAIK there is no equivalent `PS1` specifier for the fullname.

Answer (score 1):

`PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$` find this line in `.bashrc` file(vim `.bashrc` is the command) from terminal and replace that "`u`" with something you wanted and restart Terminal; hope this works :)

Comment: Will you please explain what do you suggest.

Comment: http://imgur.com/HRWemTk                                                                                                                                    http://imgur.com/FNZaqvki changed only one letter

Comment: When you are installling ubuntu  you will provide the username and computer name ,  thing is now you changed  the login details of your computer that does not change the username you provided at the time of installation , and terminal contains the details you provided at the time of installation , just check it if you want  command "whoami" gives username and command "hostname" gives computer name you have provided they are shown up on terminal not the one you changed it to

Comment: @jerry OP  wants to rename user name and not the PS prompt!

Comment: If you want to customise the names appearing on your terminal , open vim .bashrc   find the line PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$   , replace u with your username you wanted to :)

Comment: @Maythux  what i am actually trying to tell is he jus changed his login name not the user name , and he wants his login name to appear on his terminal instead of username , so i just suggested him the way to customise it